# How to add equal width of border bottom in each menu ::after?

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu and i want a border bottom in each menu on `:hover` But the problem is they are not positioned centrally of each menu as the character length of each menu are not alike.

This is my html code :

```
<div class="mymenu">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-item">Download Brochure</a></li>
 </ul
</div>
```

This is my css code :

```
.mymenu ul li{ display: inline-block;
    padding: 19px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 19px;}
.mymenu ul li a{ text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;}

.menu-item:hover::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align:center
}
```

This is what i want
[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz1rQ.jpg)   [2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU779.jpg)

This is what i get [3rd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNs1H.jpg)

Comment: show CSS for `menu-item` and parent `li`, `ul`

Comment: I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to `.mymenu li` and go from there, adjust positioning of your `:after` pseudo class (top, bottom...) and you are golden :)

Problem with your code was that `:after` elements were positioned based on `body` element since you have no positioned elements. That is why making their parent element relatively positioned helps.

Comment: Yes ! its working. but i want the width of the border-bottom should be equal for large elements. Can you please see the images i have posted. Thanks

Comment: You want to change the width, to be equal to what? I don't get it... :)